# How can mirror effect be solved on preview screen Android

Tags: android, android-camera

Earlier i ran accross a problem with my code, when i was capturing a photo, with front camera, When setting the picture to ImageView, rotation was flipped and image was using mirror effects.

The issue was solved after some research, however i am still having the issue with image beign flipped on preview screen.

Start the activity for result.. (user see the camera)

**user takes a picture (shows the preview screen, here is where i am seeing mirror effect)**

user click ok.. ImageView is set.. here the image is set perfectly no issues with mirror effect

Below is my code..

```
    private void takePhoto(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        uri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 8;

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath(),
                        options);

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

                float[] mirrorY = { -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
                Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
                matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);

                matrix.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);

                ExifInterface exifInterface = null;
                try {
                    exifInterface = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                assert exifInterface != null;
                int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        matrix.setRotate(90);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        matrix.setRotate(180);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        matrix.setRotate(270);
                        break;

                }
                rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
                visitorImage.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
                visitorPreviewImage.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        }
    }
```

My issue is i am currently unsure where i can fix the issue with mirror effect for preview screen..

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My issue is i am currently unsure where i can fix the issue with mirror effect for preview screen

The preview screen is in another Android app, not yours. There is nothing for you to "fix". A camera app will display its preview however the camera app wants.

Comment: Ok so is it possible to stop showing the preview in my app? as currently it sort of misleading to what i am trying to acheive?

Comment: @chirag90: "so is it possible to stop showing the preview in my app?" -- no, because it is not your app. It is the camera app. The user's camera app (whether pre-installed or installed by the user from the Play Store or elsewhere) will do whatever the user's camera app wants. If you need that level of control, write your own camera app, or add a library that adds camera capabilities into your own app (and gives you more control).

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks for your answer. i will take a look at libraries/create my own app. if you put that with answer provided i will accept it as answer.